# AzureDevops server - deploying to cloud VM instances

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-devops-server-2019

I've seen some [resources](https://medium.com/software-development-turkey/deploying-to-on-prem-server-with-using-azure-devops-pipelines-842f4aa226a7) and other [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sUf0wqJYXo) about deploying from Azure DevOps Services to on premises servers/VM instances.

**What about doing the opposit?** By the opposit, I mean having a on premises AzureDevops Server 2019 and willing to deploy to let's say an AWS hosted VM ?

Is there any convenient way to make an agent on the AWS side communicate with my Azure Devops server behind my company's firewal etc... As I understood there is no way to do that as the agents are clients registering for build/release jobs/tasks to run...

Did I get it right?

Is there a hint to do that?

Comment: Here is a [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/tutorial-eb.html) about deploying web application to the AWS Cloud from an Azure DevOps build definition, you can see if this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I consider that this question is on-topic, as:
It concerns "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development", otherwise we should consider closing any question about azure-devops on stackoverflow?

Comment: I don't think that this question is related to programming - otherwise, you should at least share your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give a try to the [AWS Toolkit for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools) available on the market place that should do the job.
Thanks to @Hugh Lin - MSFT !